# How to check if a key exists in boltdb

Tags: go

How do I check if a key exists on boltdb? If it was to be a map, the comma, ok syntax could be used for that. How do I do same for boltdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From bolt [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/boltdb/bolt#Bucket.Get):

> Get retrieves the value for a key in the bucket. Returns a nil value if the key does not exist or if the key is a nested bucket. The returned value is only valid for the life of the transaction.

```golang
value := b.Get([]byte("foo"))
if value == nil {
  fmt.Println("key does not exist")
}
```